# snap to time in advance in javasctipt

Tags: javascript, php

I have this small snippet in php where I was able to snap the current time to complete 5 min timeframe in advance. but i ma trying to do the same in JS. any idea what is the best way as I am new to JS?

```
<?php
$t=time();
$interval=5*60;
$last = $t - $t % $interval;
$next = $last + $interval;
echo "Next interval at ".strftime('%H:%M:%S', $next)."\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a pro, but I'm sure that you can just use this to get the time:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime();
```

full code would be something along the lines of:

```
var d = new Date();
var t = d.getTime();
var interval = 5*60*1000;
var last = t - t % interval;
var next = last - interval;
d.setTime(next);
alert('Next interval at "'+d.toTimeString().split(' ')[0]+'"');
```

EDITED: Now it works, check it out here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzhueb7b/)